# Passing parameters by ref to recursive function

Tags: perl, function, recursion, parameters, matrix

I'm trying to do a recursive function in Perl. So, I have to pass the parameters using a reference. I've tried in every way but it doesn't work.

Note that `@b` is a matrix.

The error is repeated and is `Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at LCS.pl line ...`. I don't know if it refers to `$i` or `$j` or `@b`.

Here is the code:

```
$#ARGV+1 == 2 || die "USAGE: [PROGRAM] [v] [w]\n";

my $one = shift;
my $two = shift;
my @v = split("",$one);
my @w = split("",$two);
my $n = $#v+2;
my $m = $#w+2; 
my @b;

#### DO VARIOUS OPERATIONS...

&printLCS(\$n,\$m,\@b);

##################################################
sub printLCS
{
    my $i = shift;
    my $j = shift;
    my $arrayref = shift;
    my @b=@$arrayref;

    if( ($$i == 0) || ($$j == 0) ) {
        return;
    }

    if($b[$$i][$$j] == 3) { #diag
        &printLCS(\$i-1,\$j-1,\@b);
        print $v[$$i];
    }
    elsif($b[$$i][$$j] == 1) { #up
        &printLCS(\$i-1,\$j,\@b);
    }
    else { # left
        &printLCS(\$i,\$j-1,\@b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Please, don't answer a question with another question!! However, I always use strict, vars and warnings.

Comment: Then why didn't you mention you got `Can't use string ("30762083") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see quite how anything gets into array @b ( or $b as I've redone it) but this is nearer to what you want...I think.  A brief comment on one of the lines....

```
printLCS($i-1,$j-1,[@$b]);
```

[@$b] needs more explanation.  $b is an array ref, a single scalar referring to an array
@$b converts the reference to an actual array.  So you could say @x=@$b and then use array syntax like $x[1] to get at elements in the copied $b ref'd array.  The square brackets are an array constructor that make a copy of the stuff in the square brackets.  The reason I've done this is I assume that you want unique copies of the array passed down in the recursion so that each frame is seperate.  See **perldoc perldsc** for a good treatment of these sorts of data structures.

```
$#ARGV+1 == 2 || die "USAGE: [PROGRAM] [v] [w]\n";

my $one = shift;
my $two = shift;
my @v = split("",$one);
my @w = split("",$two);
my $n = $#v+2;
my $m = $#w+2; 
my @b;

#### DO VARIOUS OPERATIONS...

printLCS($n,$m,\@b);

##################################################
sub printLCS
{
my $i = shift;
my $j = shift;
my $arrayref = shift;
my $b=$arrayref;

if(($i==0)||($j ==0))
{
    return;
}
if($b->[$i]->[$j] == 3) #diag
{
    printLCS($i-1,$j-1,[@$b]);
    print $v[$i];
}
elsif($b->[$i]->[$j] == 1) #up
{
    printLCS($i-1,$j,[@$b]);
}
else # left
{
    printLCS($i,$j-1,[@$b]);
}
}
```

Comment: @b is a matrix and there are two nested for cycle in the code that do this operation: $b[$i][$j] =  1; (it's a bit abstract but I didn't want to post all the code)

Comment: Yeah, but $i $j are decremented in every recursive call, so I thought that it was better to pass them...

Comment: Yes, there is a @b. That is the backtracking matrix

Comment: @Vorsprung, `@$b` is a read-only AoA input. No need to make a copy of it (and if you did, `[ @$b ]` wouldn't be sufficient).

Comment: ...meaning `printLCS($i-1,$j-1,$b);` is fine.